# internal comparison of string and int in python

Tags: python, python-2.x

When a string is being compared to an integer are the string and int compared with the ASCII code internally, or how is it?  I know that strings compare greater than integers, but how does that internal comparison takes place?

```
>>> "a" > 1
True
```

Comment: Possible duplication? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9306285/how-does-python-compare-strings-and-integers

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In your example, `1 < "a"` because "i" for `int` comes alphabetically before "s" for `string`.

From the [docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#comparisons):

> Objects of different types, except different numeric types and
>   different string types, never compare equal; such objects are ordered
>   consistently but arbitrarily (so that sorting a heterogeneous array
>   yields a consistent result).

I believe this was one of the things changed in python 3 (you would get a `TypeError` here).

---

As for how it is done in CPython, objects of different types except numbers are ordered by their type names; objects of the same types that don’t support proper comparison are ordered by their address.  **Note that this is part of the *implementation*, not a part of the language.**

Comment: +1 for the details and the note that is it an implementation detail.

Answer (score -2):

You should check the source of the `__gt__` method of the inbuilt string object to know the details but my guess is that the `1` is converted to a string using the `str` function and then then the two are compared.